# How to distribute python map() function over cores in Databricks?

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a function below which made some customers per customer using a fixed DataFrame.

```
def calculate_fun(customer):
  """
  Instead of loop
  """
  
  result_output = main_calculation_fun(DataFrame_1[['ColA', ColB', 'ColC', 'ColD']], DataFrame_2, customer)
    
  return pd.DataFrame(result_output)
```

Currently I run the code like this:

```
  all_result = list(map(calculate_fun, customers['customer_id'].unique().tolist()))
```

I am using DataBricks and can see I have 150+ cores and 400gb RAM. How can I distribute the customer_ids over the cores? Because right now it runs for 2+ days.

I tried the following:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()


df = spark.createDataFrame(data = pd.DataFrame(unique_contracts, columns = ['customer_id']))
DataFrame_1 = spark.createDataFrame(data = DataFrame_1)
DataFrame_2 = spark.createDataFrame(data = DataFrame_2)

def reformat(partitionData):
    for row in partitionData:
        df_result = main_calculation_fun(DataFrame_1[['ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC', 'ColD']], DataFrame_2, row.customer_id)
    
    return pd.DataFrame(df_result)
        

df2=df.rdd.mapPartitions(reformat).toDF(["A","B", "C", "D", "E"])
```

`PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object`

Comment: Please read about mapPartitions (https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-mappartitions/) seems like exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

## applyInPandas

As you are already using Pandas dataframes it might be the easiest to execute your function with [`applyInPandas`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas).

Here a sample structure which you have to addapt with your resulting schema. In addition to this your input dataframe is expected to be a Spark dataframe and it should be possible to group by `customers`.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StringType, StructField, FloatType,
    
res_schema= StructType([
        StructField('Column 1', FloatType()),
        StructField('Column 2', FloatType()),
        StructField('Column 3', StringType())
    ])

def calculate_fun(pdf):
     # applyInPandas will feed us a group converted to a Pandas dataframe to this function
     return main_calculation_fun(pdf[['ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC', 'ColD']], DataFrame_2)

all_result = df.groupBy('customer').applyInPandas(calculate_fun, schema=res_schema)
```

## Multithreading

In order to use the many cores you have, you should consider [multithreading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) on the map function. I believe it should look something like this:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

parallel_processes = 20

with Pool(parallel_processes) as p:
    all_result = p.map(calculate_fun, customers['customer_id'].unique().tolist())
```

This will introduce 20 parallel running processes. You probably can still tune yours upward depending on the resources that a single iteration needs.

**Careful**: In this case, all the processes are executed on the driver node. If your cores are distributed over multiple physical machines, you won't be able to benefit from all of them.

It is also suggested to look into the `calculate_fun` function if it can be rewritten as UDF or even fully rewritten to PySpark. This would help optimize the execution even further.

Comment: If the 150+ cores OP has aren't on the same physical machine, this won't be able to scale up to all of them.

Comment: Thanks @AKX, this is true. I added the remark, that multiprocessing is fully executed on the driver node.

Comment: @elyptikus Do I need to close the connection somehow after using multithreading? The code you provided worked great, but when I try to run something else afterwards (also using multithreading, nothing happens and cancelling the run does not work.

Comment: If you are using multiprocessing  version >3.3, the `with` statement will automatically call `__exit__()` when finished and `__exit__()` calls `p.close()`. It can be, that this is not sufficient. Try to add `p.terminate()` to the point where you want to terminate the workers and see if that helps. Docs here: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate